# Getting the video frame number in VLC

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, frame

I'm running VLC 2.0.5 on Mac OS X 10.6.8.

I have a `.mpg` video paused, and I would like to know the frame number for this moment in the video. Is there a way to reveal that in VLC?

P.S. I scrubbed back and forth through the video to reach the point it is currently paused at.

Comment: For playing back videos and examining the frame details, there is a little known jewel: [DJV](https://darbyjohnston.github.io/DJV/index.html) (I think it's written by a former Lucas' employee). This is not a player (no sound). With some configuration effort you could [display the current frame number with VLC](https://www.alphr.com/video-frame-by-frame-vlc/) but DJV has a much more [consistent interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRUM8.png). DJV is open source.

Answer (score 22):

I wanted to do the same but I couldn't find a way to do it with VLC.

But, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364861/frame-number-overlay-with-ffmpeg), you can use the [`drawtext`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1) filter in `ffmpeg` to overlay the frame number to the video permanently. So if you watch it on a player of your choice, you can always see the frame number.

For example:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mov \
    -vf "drawtext=fontfile=Arial.ttf: text=%{n}: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=0x00000099" \
    output.mov
```

Comment: Tip: one might want to add `fontsize=72` (or whatever) to the options to produce something more readable

Answer (score 11):

I don't have an OS X version, but it should be similar to the other versions.  On Windows select Tools->Media Information.  From the window that opens select the "Statistics" tab.  Under the video section you'll see the statistics for displayed and lost frames.  The frame # should be those two numbers added together.

[image: VLC Screenshot]

Comment: That assumes you've played the video from the beginning

Comment: Yes, that is true, but I don't think there is any way to get an absolute frame number.  AFAIK that information is not typically embedded in video streams.

Comment: I tried this with a nonstandard frame rate in OSX, and it didn't work at all (by the way, command-I to open it in OSX). I don't think VLC has this feature.

Comment: @heavyd Thanks for the quick reply! I did find the Media Information window, but unfortunately I scrubbed back and forth through the video, so the frame count would not be accurate...

Comment: From user [Blauhirn](http://superuser.com/users/379095/blauhirn): Concerning Tools->Media Information->Statistics: If I compare the frames counter before and after pressing e, the number doesn't increase by 1. (but, instead, randomly by up to 300).  Not knowing of another way also, I think it's simply not possible using VLC.

Comment: @heavyd The player knows the number of minutes and seconds, why can't it know the number of frames into the current second?  And from that, an absolute frame count can be found based on frames/second, if needed. (Personally I just want to know the intra-second frame number).

Answer (score 11):

Apple's Quicktime Player 7 (free download @http://support.apple.com/kb/DL923) has a dead-easy way to view frames; all you have to do is click the time in the bottom left corner and select "frames". (It also supports frame-by-frame stepping with the arrow keys.) Such a pity the feature was removed in QTX, the one that ships with OSX 10.6.8. Dont worry, though, you can install then both and they won't interfere with each other.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question.. Other software recommendations do not answer the question asked.

Answer (score 9):

With VLC 2 or 3 on OS X, one can estimate the frame number as follows:

A. ADDON: Install `Jump to time Previous Frame` via the macOS menu *VLC > Addons Manager* or the Ubuntu menu *Tools > Plugins and extensions > Addons Manager tab > Extensions*. In VLC 3, click the "Find more addons online" button. The online install page is [here](https://addons.videolan.org/p/1154013). Restart VLC.  Use VLC > Extensions > `Jump to time (Previous frame)` `[Get time >>]` button to show the `HH:MM:SS,mmm` lapse time.

B. CALCULATE/ESTIMATE: Convert `HH:MM:SS,mmm` to total lapsed seconds `SS.mmm`.  Then total_lapsed_seconds * frame_rate_per_second = frame number.

> Note: Jump To Time version 3 extension may need to be manually installed. At this time (2023.02.23) the *Addons Manager* is installing version 2.1.

[image: Jump To Time extension]

C. TIME: Use the ["Time v3.2 (intf)" VLC Extension](https://addons.videolan.org/p/1154032/) to display the running time `_,mmm` on the screen in a playing video.  A `[Efps]` format option provides a elapsed time * fps estimate. The `fps` value needs to be supplied in the format, e.g. `[E25]`

[image: Time Extension]

Comment: how do you get the .mmm to show up?  That's really all I want!

Comment: @Michael Currently, the `_,mmm` values shows in the "Jump to time" window; and, this extension does _not show `mmm`_ in VLC itself. Click to `Time format` button to rotate through various `_,mmm` formats.

Comment: @Michael One could also install the [Time](https://addons.videolan.org/p/1154032/) extension for `_,mmm` display only.

Comment: I do not understand this extension. I am ~7 seconds into the video, and the various "Get time" formats are `2125:16:51,000`, `127516:51,000`, `7651011,000`, `88/13:16:51,000`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly an answer to the OP's question, but since I tried all the above methods and found them only partially suitable for my purposes, I now use LosslessCut.app, which can display the frame number and natively allows frame-by-frame jumping back and forth, along with many other interesting features.

[LosslessCut.app Navigation Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKfTs.png)

Comment: LosslessCut displays the accurate frame time, which is great, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to single-step frames accurately. I have source video recorded at 120 fps. It steps smoothly frame by frame in VLC media player, but in LosslessCut, pressing period to advance frames doesn't always advance to a new frame. I wonder if it advances by a fixed timestep which isn't correctly matching the video frame rate?